# Swing interface for SpellChecker

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, spell-checking

I am using the Lucene 3.6 library to build a spell checker engine.

In addition , the Highlight() class is used to highlight a misspelled text.

Now will like to integrate this into a jTextField. Want the spell checker to 
function in real-time such that when the user types a word or text, 
the spell-checker engine checks the words or text and underlines the text if it is 
wrongly spelled.

The lucene spell-checker engine and HighLight class works fine when I pass a string of text from the

```
jTextArea.getText().
```

But looks like using this  method call in a loop will not be a good idea.

Any body with any idea.

Comment: Why would you need to call it in a loop. By using a `DocumentListener` you know when updates are done to the text, so no need to loop

Answer (score 0):

You can do that pretty seamlessly, using a simple KeyListener. You're writing about both JTextField and JTextArea, and this method works on both of those.

```
someTextField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // do your spell-check
        mySpellCheckMethod(someTextField.getText() + e.getKeyChar());
    }
});
```

This listener gets the KeyEvent, before someTextField adds it to its text-string, so you have to manually add the currently typed key to the string to check.
You can't, however, underline, italize (is that a word?) or bold a specific piece of the text in a TextField. It's all or nothing.